# How can I tell Google Chrome to use the larger icon for application shortcuts?

Tags: html, google-chrome, shortcut-file

Google Chrome allows you to save websites as application shortcuts with an icon on the user's desktop. Unfortunately the icon it adds to the desktop is a scaled up version of the 16x16 version.
The icon is an icon file that contains images in several resolutions and is saved in the root of the website. No code in the header of the site mentions the favicon.
The icon file itself seem to work. IE is displaying the larger icons just fine.

[image: the icon and the result]

Has anybody had the same problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is due to a bug:

- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5126
- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92954

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it seems like it is a indeed a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have found wordaround for this. Not a very convincing one though. Websites like Gmail, Google Search, Google Drive etc can be added as apps (they are just shortcuts/links) from Chrome web store. (Some of them come by default with Google Chrome installation)

Install chrome launcher from here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/launcher
Open chrome launcher from your windows taskbar. Select the website shortcut/app and drag it to taskbar. Now you have a higher resolution icon.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put this HTML in your webpage:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

This will tell Chrome that it should use the entire file as is instead of converting 16x16 to bigger sizes.